# Ruby : Could not find RedCloth-4.2.9

Tags: ruby

I am very new to this, How can I resolve this issue?

```
$ rake
Could not find RedCloth-4.2.9 in any of the sources
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you don't have the `RedCloth` gem installed that's it.

If you are using Bundler gem, which I suppose, you can type `bundle install` to install it, otherwise you can manually install it via `gem install RedCloth`.

Comment: I did that, but whenever I do `rake install`, it gives me a new package missing, is there a way to tell it to install all dependencies it needs? rather than doing `gem install` for whatever it says missing?

Comment: the flag `-y` or `--include-dependencies` should work, but please use the inline reference.

Comment: @daydreamer I have the same issue. What fixed it?

Comment: I guess fresh install of rvm

Comment: FWIW, I ran into this and needed to reinstall bundler.

Answer (score 1):

I was having similar issues and the main thing that helped was running `bundle update`.